# Markov Arrival Operator with non deterministic transition

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, curves, markov-process

I'm writing my MDP's value function, and I wish to find a formulation which will result a switching curve.
I have arrival operator, as described in Koole's book:
https://www.nowpublishers.com/article/DownloadSummary/STO-002

For example:
$V(a,b)=min{(V(a,b)+C,V(a+1,b))}$

But my environment operator is non deterministic. The Value function operator is:
$V(a,b)=min{(V(a,b)+C,p1*V(a+1,b)+(1-p1)*V(a,b+1))}$

In Koole, all the operators are deterministic, meaning the min is always between two deterministic states.
I have here an action which can lead to two different states, with p1 probability.

Is there any article or book that proves this kind of non deterministic arrival operators?